# how to get better test error/accuracy with neural networks?

Tags: neural-network, matlab

This is Neural Network Pattern Recognition.I used a vec dataset 1*54149 and 1*54149 target and I'm trying to train my neural network to do binary classification (1 and 0).i want get best ?

```
clear all;   
clc;   
load vec; load target;     
inputs = double(vec);    
targets = double(target);      

% Create a Pattern Recognition Network    
hiddenLayerSize = 1;    
%net = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize);    
net = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize);    

% Choose Input and Output Pre/Post-Processing Functions    
% For a list of all processing functions type: help nnprocess     
net.inputs{1}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapstd'};     
net.outputs{2}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapstd'};     


% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing     
% For a list of all data division functions type: help nndivide      
net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';     
net.divideMode = 'sample';  % Divide up every sample     
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 50/100;     
net.divideParam.valRatio = 25/100;      
net.divideParam.testRatio = 25/100;     

% For a list of all training functions type: help nntrain      
net.trainFcn = 'trainrp';        

% Choose a Performance Function      
% For a list of all performance functions type: help nnperformance      
net.performFcn = 'mse';         

% Choose Plot Functions      
% For a list of all plot functions type: help nnplot      
net.plotFcns = {'plotperform','plottrainstate','ploterrhist', ...    
  'plotregression', 'plotfit'};       


% Train the Network      
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);      

% Test the Network      
outputs = net(inputs);       
errors = gsubtract(targets,outputs);       
performance = perform(net,targets,outputs);        
[tpr,fpr,thresholds] = roc(targets,outputs);        

% Recalculate Training, Validation and Test Performance      
trainTargets = targets .* tr.trainMask{1};      
valTargets = targets  .* tr.valMask{1};      
testTargets = targets  .* tr.testMask{1};     
trainPerformance = perform(net,trainTargets,outputs);      
valPerformance = perform(net,valTargets,outputs);       
testPerformance = perform(net,testTargets,outputs);         


% View the Network      
view(net)       

 %Plots      
% Uncomment these lines to enable various plots.      
figure, plotperform(tr)      
figure, plottrainstate(tr)        
figure, plotconfusion(targets,outputs)     
figure, ploterrhist(errors)      
figure, plotregression(targets,outputs)     
figure, plotroc(targets,outputs)
```

So please someone can help me . thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your hiddenLayerSize of 1 is extremely small.  This would only allow classification of linearly separable data (i.e. data that when plotted you could easily draw a line between the two classes.)

Try hiddenLayerSize of 10 and go up as needed to get better results.  It is always best to start small to see if a simple solution is possible.  With 54149 you may need to go much higher, but it depends on the complexity of the problem.

When you train the data will be divided into training, validation and test sets.  Training will automatically stop generalization to the validation data has peaked.  The accuracy on the test data (which is not used for training or stopping) will be a good measure of how well the network can be expected to generalize to similar new data.